# Include remoted Library (API 4.5 Mapy.cz) to Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I am confused. I'am trying to make little chrome extension (popup) and I need connect to remoted API.
This is, what I would use, if it is a standard web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api4.mapy.cz/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Loader.load();</script>
```

I experimented with including new element *script* to *head* (not works for me). But I couldn't believe, there is no easier way...

Please, show me the best way.

---

**EDIT:**

Linking the API loader is fine and works. Thanks to @serg. So, my code of popup looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api4.mapy.cz/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Loader.load();
    var center = SMap.Coords.fromWGS84(16.61574, 49.20315);
</script>
```

Object Loader is defined and it is OK. Loader should load the whole API either object SMap. But SMap is undefined. What next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ask developer from Mapy.cz and they gave the solution. Instead of using Loader.load() which cause including additional script and async load - use this way:

```
Loader.async = true;
Loader.load(null, null, function(){
    alert(123); // it works...
    // custom code calling objects etc. from API
    // ...
});
```

[Final Example of usage](http://www.latte.cz/pub/GoogleChromeExtensionWithMapyCz.zip)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make ajax requests to this remote API, you need to list API domain in the permissions in your manifest:

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "http://api4.mapy.cz/"
  ],
}
```

Comment: I need include this javascript script to my extension to use methods from the library. It's API for maps, like maps.google.com.

Comment: @Jaroslav Open popup console and check if there any errors (right click on popup icon and select inspect).

Comment: There is naturally error: "Loader is not defined". But there is something wired: when I try work with API from console, it works! (If I include <script tag in head)

Comment: @Jaroslav it must be something specific to this API. You can include and use any external script in popup without problems.